# Saving array of data in multiple rows in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

in my laravel application, I have the following form to submit datas

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'testresults.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group">



            <strong>Test ID:</strong>


            @foreach ($getTests as $object)

                {!! Form::text('test_id', ''.$object->id .'', array('placeholder' => 'Test Name','class' => 'form-control','readonly')) !!}

                
            @endforeach


        </div>

    </div>


   

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

       <table class="table table-bordered">

  <tr>

     <th>Test</th>

     <th width="280px">Result</th>

  </tr>

    @foreach ($getTests as $key => $getTest)

    
       
            
            @foreach (explode(',', $getTest->samp_list) as $samp_list)
                <tr>
                <td>
                 {!! Form::text('test_type[]', ''.$samp_list.'', array('placeholder' => 'Test Type','class' => 'form-control','readonly')) !!}    
                </td>
                <td>{!! Form::text('test_result[]', null, array('placeholder' => 'Test Result','class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach 

        

    

    @endforeach

</table>

    </div>

     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <div class="form-group">



            <strong>Test By:</strong>

                {!! Form::text('test_by', ''.Auth::user()->name .'', array('placeholder' => 'Test Name','class' => 'form-control','readonly')) !!}


        </div>

    </div>




    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </div>

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is my `create.blade.php`

And my controller looks like this

```
public function store(Request $request)

    {
        try{

            request()->validate([

            'test_id' => 'required',

            'test_type' => 'required',

            'test_result' => 'required',

            'test_by' => 'required',

        ]);

    

        TestResult::create($request->all());

    

        return redirect()->route('testresults.index')

                        ->with('success','Test Type created successfully.');

        }

        catch(Exception $e){

            return redirect()->route('testresults.create')

                        ->with('failed','An error has been occured.');
        }
   

    }
```

Now the problem is, whenever I tried to store the data, they save it as arrays in the database.

Eg:test_type will save as something like ["TS","Cu ion content"] and test_result will save as ["3","45%"] in the same row.

But I want those data to be saved in separate rows in string format.

Eg:

```
row1-> id |1 and test_type | TS and test_result | 3
row2-> id |2 and test_type | Cu ion content and test_result | 45%
.....
rown-> id |n and test_type | N and test_result | n
```

In my model, I have this,

```
protected $casts = [
        'test_type' => 'array',
        'test_result' => 'array',
    ];
```

Once I remove it, I'm getting an error saying

```
ErrorException Array to string conversion
```

Now the issue is, all the records are save as arrays in the same row...

Comment: Have you tried running a foreach loop and trigger the save option inside the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
   $test_result=$request->test_result;

    foreach($request->test_type as $item => $value)
    $data[$value]=array(
        'test_id'=>$request->test_id,
        'test_type'=>$value,
        'user_id'=>$test_result[$item],
        'test_by'=>$request->test_by,
    );
    
    TestResult::insert($data); // Eloquent approach
```

i hope you got your solution .